# Relationship between volume density and area density

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\mu(x)dx$ be a measure in $\mathbb{R}^{2n-2}$, where $\mu$ (a  $C^\infty$ and positive function) is the density of the volume in the sense that $\DeclareMathOperator{\Vol}{\mathrm{Vol}} \Vol_\mu(B_r)=\int_{B_r}\mu(x)dx$, where $B_r$ be the ball of radius $r$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2n-2}$. Now suppose that $\mu(x)dx=d\Gamma$: by Stokes's theorem we get
$$\Vol_\mu(B_r)=\int_{B_r}\mu(x)dx=\int_{B_r}d\Gamma=\int_{S_r}\Gamma$$
where $S_t$ is the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{2n-3}$. **The question is**: can we express the area of $S_r$ as a function of the density $\mu$?

Comment: Do you want to express the Euclidean area of $S_r$ in terms of $\mu$ or do you want to *define* an area density in terms of $\mu$? The former, I think it can't be done in general, the latter can be done in a multitude of ways. For instance, take the derivative of the $\mu$ volume of $B_r$.

Answer (score -1):

Denote by $A_R$ the area of the ball $B_R$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ of radius $R$, and denote by $r$ the radial coordinate, then
$$A_R=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\delta(r-R)\mu(\mathbf{x})\,d\mathbf{x},$$
with $\delta(r)$ the [Dirac delta function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)

Example in three dimensions, $d=3$, with measure $\mu(\mathbf{x})\,d\mathbf{x}=r^2 \sin\theta\, drd\theta d\phi$ in spherical coordinates,

$$A_R=\int_0^\infty \delta(r-R) r^2 dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^\pi \sin \theta d\theta =4\pi R^2.$$